# How to make ABC work with Boost.Python/C++ Classes?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, abc

I want `abc.abstractmethod` to work on the following class:

```
from abc import ABC
from my_cpp_module import my_class

class A(my_class, ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def implement_me(self, arg):
        '''not implemented'''

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()                    <--- should throw
b.implement_me('hallo')
```

But this little example gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./abc-test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class A(my_class, ABC):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Fiddling a bit with `type`, classes and so on I get an implementation that runs without error:

```
class MyABC(type(my_class), ABCMeta): 
    pass  # type(my_class) == <class 'Boost.Python.class'>

class A(my_class, metaclass=MyABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def implement_me(self, arg):
        '''not implemented'''
```

.. but in this case `b = B()` just works, too but (of course) I want it to produce the following error:

```
File "./abc-test.py", line 22, in <module>
    b = B()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods implement_me
```

Is there a way to make `abstractmethod` work together with Boost.Python classes like expected?

Comment: Hi frans- working throught the same issue.  Haven't come up with an answer, but I believe the problem is with the `__new__` method.  Usually, `ABCMeta.__new__` is going to check all members for `__isabstractmethod__`.  However, it looks like boost objects contain their own `__new__` method which is somehow covering up the ABC one.